# file not found when adding plugin in phonegap 3.4 for ios

Tags: cordova, ios7, phonegap-plugins

I have just begin with phonegap and I am trying to install the barcode plugin for iOS, following the [official documentation](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.4.0/guide_cli_index.md.html#The%20Command-Line%20Interface). However when adding the plugin with cordova, some files are not found.

I am working with iOS 7 on Mavericks with phonegap and cordova version 3.4.

Thanks!

```
$ phonegap create barcode com.ramon.barcode BarCode
[phonegap] missing library com.ramon.barcode/www/3.4.0
[phonegap] downloading https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.4.0.tar.gz...
[phonegap] the options /Users/mingot/Downloads/prova/barcode com.ramon.barcode BarCode
[phonegap] created project at /Users/mingot/Downloads/prova/barcode
$ cd barcode/
$ cordova platform add ios
Creating ios project...
$ cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
Fetching plugin "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" via plugin registry
Installing "com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner" for ios
Error during processing of action! Attempting to revert...
Failed to install 'com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner':Error: Uh oh!
cannot find "/path/to/project/barcode/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm" ios <source-file>
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/ios.js:45:48)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/action-stack.js:46:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:553:20)
    at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:303:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
Error: Uh oh!
cannot find "/path/to/project/barcode/plugins/com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner/src/ios/CDVBarcodeScanner.mm" ios <source-file>
    at module.exports.source-file.install (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/platforms/ios.js:45:48)
    at Object.ActionStack.process (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/util/action-stack.js:46:25)
    at handleInstall (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:553:20)
    at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/plugman/src/install.js:303:20
    at _fulfilled (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:798:54)
    at self.promiseDispatch.done (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:827:30)
    at Promise.promise.promiseDispatch (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:760:13)
    at /usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:574:44
    at flush (/usr/local/share/npm/lib/node_modules/cordova/node_modules/q/q.js:108:17)
    at process._tickCallback (node.js:415:13)
```

Comment: You've got `cannot find "/path/to/project...` in your log file. Is your project configured correctly?

Comment: I changed the real path to not reveal private information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple. File in https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-app-hello-world/archive/3.4.0.tar.gz was corrupted. Try this one, https://github.com/Scandit/BarcodeScannerPlugin

Answer (score 1):

I was having the same issue when trying to instll the com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner plugin into my project.  (although I'm using Cordova, not Phonegap).

```
cordova plugin add com.phonegap.plugins.barcodescanner
```

Getting the same error. Not really sure what is going on there.

As a workaround, the barcode scanner plugin can be added via git:

```
cordova plugin add https://github.com/wildabeast/BarcodeScanner.git
```

This seems to work OK, and achieves the same thing.